# Redirect page according to window size

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I am working on a project using Bootstrap 3 and I want to redirect the user to a page that indicates that they need to rotate their gadget. 
For instance, if they are using a smartphone in landscape mode, I want to render a page that indicates them to rotate their phones. It is not an alert, but a page with a image with the rotate signal. 
So, I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(window).width() <= 480) && ($(window).width() >=320) {
      document.location = "[path to]/rotate.html";
   }
});
```

It not only does not work, but it also messes the other script that I made to deal with specific elements when window is resized.

EDIT: 
Answer from @Varinder fixed the problem perfectly (Thanks!), but now I have the issue with the "else" statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ( ($(window).width() <= 480) && ($(window).width() >=320) ) {
      document.location = "rotate.html";
   }
   else {
   $(window).resize(function(){
    document.location = "index.html"
   ;});
   }
});
```

It just does not happen. After it redirects to rotate.html, it stays there in every other window size.

**FINAL EDIT:**
Thanks to @Varinder and @azeós, everything is fixed. I wrapped all the content in a new div (`.content`) and the only thing outside is the content for the rotate page. That works perfectly.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you use media queries and show the image in a hidden div instead of redirecting the user to another page?

Comment: This is a mockup of what I mean: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EcSXm/)

Answer (score 1):

probably need to wrap `if` condition

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ( ($(window).width() <= 480) && ($(window).width() >=320) ) {
      document.location = "[path to]/rotate.html";
   }
});
```

**Edit:**

As @azeós mentioned it, if your intention is to show different information when user rotates her devices then probably best to use [media queries](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/)

And there is also `orientationchange` event

```
    $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( e ) {
        if ( e.orientation ) {
            if( e.orientation == "portrait" ){
                // do something
            }
            else if( e.orientation == "landscape" ) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Looks like the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem. Just one more question (sorry for the silly questions, I am new to it): Now, I need a "else" statement to put the page back to the original when user rotates. I edited my original post with the new issue... Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again, Varinder! I was not thinking on the next page, as @azeós pointed out, now I understand. Thanks for your time, your patience and your instructions. All the best

Answer (score 1):

You'll end up with a redirect loop if you do it that way. You need to check if you already are in on of those pages.

You really have just two pages to show up (rotate.html and index.html)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentUrl = window.location.pathname.replace('/', '');
    function rotate() {
        if (($(window).width() <= 480) && ($(window).width() >= 320)) {
            if (currentUrl != 'rotate.html') {
                document.location = 'rotate.html';
            }
        } else {
            if (currentUrl != 'index.html') {
                document.location = 'index.html';
            }
        }
    }
    rotate();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        rotate();
    });
});
```

Take in mind, that if you have more than just `index.html`, you'll have to make some changes. Because if the user is in `page2.html` and rotates his phone, will get redirected to `rotate.html`, and when he rotates again, instead of going back to `page2.html`, will end up in `index.html`.

I think that the CSS approach with media queries is a better solution: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EcSXm/)

Comment: Thank you very much, not only for the answer, but also for the instructions on the media queries. It really helps!